# How to terminate an integer-input loop with a character?

Tags: c++, while-loop, char, int, cin

New to Stack and C++.
I want to terminate a loop that regurgitates numbers fed to it with a character. Say, Q for Quit. The following program is functional and free of syntax errors. How can I terminate this loop without editing the input parameter?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    bool run = true;

    while(run)
    {
    cout<<"Enter your two favorite numbers."<<endl;

    int num1;
    int num2;

    cin>>num1>>num2;

    cout<<"You entered "<<num1<<" and "<<num2<<"."<<endl;

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the [`break` statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break). But you'll also then need to read a string for the first input, rather than an integer.

```
while(run)
{
    cout<<"Enter your two favorite numbers, or 'Q' to exit."<<endl;

    string input;
    int num1;
    int num2;

    cin>>input1;

    if (input == "Q")
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        num1 = stoi(input);
    }

    cin>>num2;

    cout<<"You entered "<<num1<<" and "<<num2<<"."<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Parse, of course! I had issues with syntax in the break statement as well and after a little bit of adjustment and it came to pass around that David was right in the first place. Also experimenting with the possibility of maintaining the Boolean variable in the if/else statements.Thanks for the edit.